# Excel 数式で対象行、対象列だけ抜き出して新たに表を作りたい

Tags: excel

エクセルで以下のようなテーブルがあったとします。

| 対象行フラグ | データ１ | データ２ | データ３ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ○ | AAA | BBB | CCC |
|  | DDD | EEE | FFF |
| ○ | GGG | HHH | III |
| ○ | JJJ | KKK | LLL |
|  | MMM | NNN | OOO |

ここから対象行フラグが○になっている行のデータ１とデータ２を抜き出して

| データ１ | データ２ |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | BBB |
| GGG | HHH |
| JJJ | KKK |

というようなテーブルを数式で作りたいです。
どのような数式を組めばいいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 1番目のテーブルと2番目のテーブルは別シートですか？「データ1」「データ2」以外に処理用のデータが入力されることは許容されますか？　また、回答の重複を避けるためにも質問者さん自身が調べたことや試されたことを質問に追記してください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILTER` 関数を使うとできます https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/filter-%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

たとえば元のテーブルが A 列から D 列にあったとして、以下のようにできます。

```
=filter(A:C, A:A = "○")
```

Comment: なにかVLOOKUP的なもので頑張るのかと思ってたのですが、こんな便利なものがあるんですね。